# Is there a way to catch in a variable the output of a function after it is called by an ipywidgets button click?

Tags: python-3.x, ipywidgets

I am working on a project that uses ipywidgets and I have a question concerning the button on_click method. I am trying to store the output of the function that is called by the button in a variable (without having to make it global). Here is a simplified example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

my_btn = widgets.Button(description='Press me!', disabled=False, button_style='', tooltip='Click me', icon = '')

def affect_value():
    return 10

display(my_btn)

x = my_btn.on_click(affect_value)
```

So I know this cannot work because the variable is being affected a value before the button is clicked, but at least it shows what I am trying to do (I hope).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`on_click` doesn't return anything, so assigning it to x gives you None. This is pretty common misconception; the `on_click` or `observe` function only associates the widget with the function as a side effect.

To solve the problem, you could create an instance of basic class and assign values to that.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

my_btn = widgets.Button(description='Press me!', disabled=False, button_style='', tooltip='Click me', icon = '')

class ValueHolder():
    x: int = None

vh = ValueHolder()

def affect_value(btn):
    vh.x = 10

display(my_btn)

my_btn.on_click(affect_value)
```